# pyspark error: AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'parallelize'

Tags: python, hadoop, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark on Jupyter notebook. Here is how Spark setup:

```
import findspark
findspark.init(spark_home='/home/edamame/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6-hive', python_path='python2.7')

    import pyspark
    from pyspark.sql import *

    sc = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("yarn-client").config("spark.executor.memory", "2g").config('spark.driver.memory', '1g').config('spark.driver.cores', '4').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

Then when I do:

```
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_in)
```

where `df_in` is a pandas dataframe. I then got the following errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-1db231ce21c9> in <module>()
----> 1 spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_in)


/home/edamame/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6-hive/python/pyspark/sql/context.pyc in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio)
    297         Py4JJavaError: ...
    298         """
--> 299         return self.sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema, samplingRatio)
    300 
    301     @since(1.3)

/home/edamame/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6-hive/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio)
    520             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    521         else:
--> 522             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    523         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    524         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

/home/edamame/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6-hive/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    400         # convert python objects to sql data
    401         data = [schema.toInternal(row) for row in data]
--> 402         return self._sc.parallelize(data), schema
    403 
    404     @since(2.0)

AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'parallelize'
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`SparkSession` is not a replacement for a `SparkContext` but an equivalent of the `SQLContext`. Just use it use the same way as you used to use `SQLContext`:

```
spark.createDataFrame(...)
```

and if you ever have to access `SparkContext` use `sparkContext` attribute:

```
spark.sparkContext
```

so if you need `SQLContext` for backwards compatibility you can:

```
SQLContext(sparkContext=spark.sparkContext, sparkSession=spark)
```

Comment: I then tried: spark_df = sc.createDataFrame(df_in) , but the spark_df seems to be corrupted. Is spark_df = sc.createDataFrame(df_in) the right way to do the conversion here?

Comment: Only if `df_in` is a valid argument for `createDataFrame`.

Comment: df_in is a pandas dataframe. I thought it should be valid?

Answer (score 9):

Whenever we are trying to create a DF from a backward-compatible object like RDD or a data frame created by spark session, you need to make your SQL context-aware about your session and context.

Like Ex:

If I create a RDD:

```
ss=SparkSession.builder.appName("vivek").master('local').config("k1","vi").getOrCreate()

rdd=ss.sparkContext.parallelize([('Alex',21),('Bob',44)])
```

But if we wish to create a df from this RDD, we need to

`sq=SQLContext(sparkContext=ss.sparkContext, sparkSession=ss)`

then only we can use SQLContext with RDD/DF created by pandas.

```
schema = StructType([
   StructField("name", StringType(), True),
   StructField("age", IntegerType(), True)])
df=sq.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
df.collect()
```