# Convert list into pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a list of tuples which has been fetched from mysql db. I need to convert it into pyspark dataframe.

my code looks like below:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39 pyspark-shell"

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('recommendation_clustering').getOrCreate()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
    final_result = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldb",
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        dbtable="(select movie_id, genres from  program) as rating",
        user="user",
        password="password",
        properties={"driver": 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'}
    ).load().take(3)
```

The type of final_result is list and it looks like as follows:

> [Row(movie_id='0-0-10', genres='[Comedy]'), Row(movie_id='0-0-1113',
>   genres='[Music]'), Row(movie_id='0-0-1132', genres='[Music]')])

I need to convert it into pyspark dataframe.

I tried
`sqlDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(final_result,["movie_id","genres"])` but got error message.

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'parallelize'

Comment: Do you need to use `take(3)` ? Because without that, `final_result` is already a pyspark dataframe.

Comment: i thought there was a dataframe, not a pyspark dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you mentioned in comments, `AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'parallelize'` maybe because you are trying to create a `SQLContext` using `SparkSession`. `SparkSession` is a  unified entry point for manipulating data with Spark and you dont need to create `SQLContext` separately. Directly use `spark` variable to read the data.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39521419/7045987) for more details.

Also, you are already getting the data `final_result` in a pyspark dataframe if you just use `spark` instead of `sqlContext`.

Comment: when I removed take function, I got the output as 
DataFrame[movie_id: string, genres: string]

Comment: Yes! That is your pyspark dataframe. write `final_result.show()` to see the data.

Comment: Got it.. I'm new to spark.  Thank you so much.